# Python connection error when called through docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have this very simple python code:

```
import psycopg2

postgres_credentials = {
    "host": "postgres_mcdonalds",
    "database_name": "postgres",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "password"
}

filename = "FastFoodNutritionMenu.csv"

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=postgres_credentials["host"],
    database=postgres_credentials["database_name"],
    user=postgres_credentials["user"],
    password=postgres_credentials["password"],
    port="5432",
)
print("Sucess!")
```

Called main.py
And its Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I would like to connect my python script in a postgres database which be build and up previously:

```
services:
  postgres_mcdonalds:
    image: postgres:14.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      PORT : "5432"
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgres
    
volumes:
  postgres_volume:
```

I don't know why but when I run the line to call my docker image from my dockerfile, I receive the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//main.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

To call my image, I ran:
docker build -t test_postgres .
docker run test_postgres

Why the python code isn't work when I call through docker?
If I call from python main.py, the "Success" is returned as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much, have a nice day!

Comment: The name of the container is local to the docker-compose environment that you created earlier. it's not available to the simple docker command. If you want to be able to connect by name you need to put them in the same docker-compose.

Comment: The docker inspect should get you an IP address that you would be able to reference from your python code instead of the hostname.

Comment: It is true, but if I run docker inspect 0-postgres-docker-config_postgres_mcdonalds_1, 
and get the ip address and put it instead of localhost in postgres_credentials dict and run: 
docker build -t test_postgres . docker run test_postgres
Its take to much time and return:
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "192.168.176.2", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: I can connect to postgres database through beekeeper setting host as localhost, and running the python script outside from docker in the same way and get success. Why if run I the script using docker, I can't make the connection?

Comment: The docker-compose network will be completely independent of the plain old docker network - they won't be able to talk to each other, unless you make them all share the same network. I'm guessing the compose name is `0-postgres-docker-config`, so the network will be `0-postgres-docker-config_default`, so the docker run command should have the argument `--network 0-postgres-docker-config_default` to get it to share the same network. Once you do that, you'll be also able to use the name `postgres_mcdonalds` directly.

Comment: It looks like the database configuration you're showing isn't getting used – it looks like you're trying to (correctly) connect to `postgres_mcdonalds` but the error message is about `localhost`.  Conversely, you say you get the error from `docker build`, but it doesn't look like anything in your Dockerfile would try to connect to the database.  Can you double-check these details?  (As @AnyaShenanigans notes you can't connect to the database at all from the Dockerfile, and if that is part of your problem you may need to do something like run migrations from an entrypoint wrapper script.)

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans it works!
I needed just add the network, when I ran this way it works:
docker run --network 0-postgres-docker-config_default test_postgres

Thank you!